# offline html5 google analytics tracking

Tags: html, google-analytics, tracking, offline, dispatch

I realize this question has been asked before but they seem to be a couple years old.

I have a HTML5 based application that can work in offline mode.  How can I track interactions in this app?

I have Google Analytics implemented and can include the ga file in the cache manifest.  Based on my readings, it seems that Google is now caching all requests by default and then using a "dispatch" method to send all those events to their servers.

However, I cannot find exact confirmation of this.  How does google decide when to fire the dispatch method?  Is it checking for connection internally?  Can I force it to not fire the dispatch method until I am sure that network is available?  Can I have multiple sessions be cached offline and then fire the dispatch method?

Thank you,